# C#, can't serialize to binary

Tags: c#, serialization

I follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C) online exactly but somehow it's giving me errors.  Saying there is no object map or something.

I have the following static object that I want to serialize:

```
[Serializable]
public class Settings : ISerializable 
{
    public static string server= "http://localhost/";
    public static string username = "myname";
    public static bool savePassword = true;
    public static bool autoSync = true;
    public static string password = "mypass";
    public static string folderPath1= "c:/";
    public static string folderPath2= "c:/";
    public static string autoSyncDuration = "300";
    public static string lastSyncTime = "???";


    public Settings()
    { }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Type myTypeObj = Type.GetType("Settings");
        foreach (FieldInfo p in myTypeObj.GetFields())
        {
            Object value = p.GetValue(null);
            info.AddValue(p.Name, value, p.GetType());
        }
    }

    public Settings(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Type myTypeObj = Type.GetType("Settings");
        FieldInfo p;
        foreach (SerializationEntry e in info)
        {
            p = myTypeObj.GetField(e.Name);
            p.SetValue(null, e.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the Read/Write functions:

```
    private void writeSettings()
    {
        pcb_savingSettings.Visible = true;
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(settingFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fileStream, new Settings());

        fileStream.Close();
        pcb_savingSettings.Visible = false;
    }
    private void readSettings()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(settingFile))
        {
            writeSettings();
        }
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(settingFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
```

ACTUAL ERROR MSG:  No map for Object '822476800'.  This occur on this line:

```
bf.Deserialize(fileStream);
```

Comment: Can you copy the exact error message?

Comment: "the tutorial". What tutorial? Link please.

Comment: @Oded the one and only tutorial available on the internet obviously.

Comment: "or something" is not helpful. Tell us the actual message please.

Comment: @CodeInChaos nah, I wrote the one and only binary serialization tutorial, and it didn't use `BinaryFormatter` ;p

Comment: Why do you want to use `BinaryFormatter` for settings? It's certainly not a good fit for this. (And I'd argue for anything). I'd look into a Json or XML serializer.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Was it the one about `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: hmm, with that simple class ISerializable is not needed I think [Serializable] attribute is suffficient. And wrap filestream in usings.

Comment: yeuck, hacking static members into the stream like that is *horrible* - a quasi-singleton would have been *so much* easier and cleaner - you wouldn't have had to do any of those hacks

Comment: I added the actual error msg!

Comment: @Oded grgrgrgrgrgrggrggrgrgrrgrrrrrr

Comment: @MarcGravell - did you mean `<ouch>grgrgrgrgrgrggrggrgrgrrgrrrrrr</ouch>`?

Comment: Just to let everyone know, the advantage of this "hack" is that I can add field in the future without having to change the serialization function!

Comment: You don't need to "hack" anything to be able to add properties in the future. Simple create a normal class marked as `Serializable` with non-static members - since these properties are all simple types (string and int) they will automatically be serialized/deserialized. Recommend too that your variables not be `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what the error is for those in future who might be banging their head wondering what went wrong.  It's actually really simple.  A small typo actually.  Too bad M$ have horrible error message that don't really tell you where the error might have happened:

Simply replace this line:

```
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    Type myTypeObj = Type.GetType("Settings");
    foreach (FieldInfo p in myTypeObj.GetFields())
    {
        Object value = p.GetValue(null);
        info.AddValue(p.Name, value, p.GetType());
    }
}
```

With this:

```
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        Type myTypeObj = Type.GetType("Settings");
        foreach (FieldInfo p in myTypeObj.GetFields())
        {
            Object value = p.GetValue(null);
            info.AddValue(p.Name, value, value.GetType());
        }
    }
```

And that's it!  Everything serialize/de-serialize just fine.  You can't possibly guess where it went wrong with the error msg:  * No map for Object '822476800'*.

Note: In the last line,  p.GetType should be value.GetType

Comment: Read carefully, it is definitely NOT the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I'll preface this answer with this is a bad idea.  Serialization is designed to serialize an object instance and static fields are not part of that instance.

I believe that when you do have a custom serializer, you need to preface the object name with **static.**.  For example, public static member named A would need added as **static.A**.

Here's a link that should help:  http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=411604