# c# - deserializing large object

Tags: c#, serialization, tcp, bittorrent, monotorrent

I have a chat that has a file sharing system that I built by slightly modifying monotorrent.

When a user shares a file the client serializes the Monotorrent.common.torrent object (represents a .torrent file) and sends it to the server inside of another object and the server deserialize it. This works only when the file that the user shares is small(about less than 1 MB). When its larger the server gives the following exeption:

> Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible
>   causes are invalid stream or object version change between
>   serialization and deserialization.

This is my deserialization code:

```
public CommendData ByteArrayToCommendData(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(arrBytes))
    {
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        CommendData obj = (CommendData)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

(CommendData contains the Monotorrent.common.torrent object in this instance)

Comment: Have you checked your config file to make sure you aren't hitting a throughput limit?

Comment: What config file are you referring to?

Comment: The app.config or web.config file that initializes your C# application.

Comment: My app.config file has nothing in it :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
</configuration>

Comment: That's my point.  You are using the default configuration.  There are limits on the amount of data that can be transferred by default and you may be hitting one of those limits.  The default value for maxRequestLength is 4 MB as indicated in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548305/maximum-value-of-maxrequestlength)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration maxAllowedContentLength="10000000">
 
</configuration>
correct? because it tells me that "The 'maxAllowedContentLength' attribute is not allowed"

Comment: No, that is not correct.  If you google maxAllowedContentLength you will find the correct usage in [this StackOverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022434/how-to-set-the-maxallowedcontentlength-to-500mb-while-running-on-iis7).  BTW, the default for maxAllowedContentLength is 30 MB.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I did this - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits>
          <headerLimits>
            <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="4294967295 " />
          </headerLimits>
        </requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
but still the same error :(

Comment: Try adding this to your config file: `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097951"/>`

Comment: tried this too <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Comment: Tried the <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097951"/> also didn't work any other ideias? BTW
on a 3 MB file it the error was :No map for object '{0}'

Comment: Well, you're getting a different error so that's progress.  I googled your error message and [found this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986296/c-cant-serialize-to-binary). That may not be your problem but it seems to indicate (as the error says) that there is a problem with your deserialization map, possibly a small typo that you're not seeing.  Good luck.

Comment: It happends only on that file on other files its the original error so I think the solution is not with the new error, any ideias on what to do next, i tried to serealize with ProtoBuf but got the error "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred" and coudnt fined a solution that works :(